# Unable to connect to server wen running c# test (Nunit)

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I want to run the test in c# but it gives me the following error:

`System.Net.WebException :Unable to connect to the remote server ..>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made becausethe target machine actively refuces it 127.0.0.1:4444 .`

How can i solve?

Comment: Do you connect to a local web service in the code being executed?

Comment: it was my mistake . i didn't configure everything correctly . Did it again and worked .

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to Web Resources is not part of Unit Testing.

In Unit Tests, such calls are replaced by other items which provide the same interface and are configured in a way useful for the test - that's often called "mocking".

You may write the mock classes on your own, or yo can use frameworks, e.g. Moq, RhinoMocks, etc.